# convert h2o.ensemble levelone data to a dataframe

Tags: r, h2o

I am trying to convert the levelone matrix of cross validation predictions from my h2o.ensemble into a normal R object (dataframe) so I can work with the data. I can retrieve the levelone matrix from my h2o.ensemble (fit). When I try to convert to a dataframe I get a bunch of java errors.

```
> levelone_h2o <- fit$levelone
> print(levelone_h2o)
  h2o.glm.wrapper h2o.randomForest.wrapper h2o.gbm.wrapper h2o.deeplearning.wrapper     y
1        6647.155                 1609.284        4617.418                 3839.470  1600
2        9383.599                13436.505       18496.432                13803.004 13500
3        2499.189                 8807.916        9859.840                 5697.766  2200
4       11541.062                 8067.081       12338.893                 6955.093  5750
5       12884.708                14544.741       16254.272                14843.988 14500
6        5757.545                 6501.096       10247.327                 4794.154  6250

[122653 rows x 5 columns] 
> df <- as.data.frame(levelone_h2o)

ERROR: Unexpected HTTP Status code: 500 Server Error (url = http://localhost:54321/3/DownloadDataset?frame_id=RTMP_sid_bce4_12&hex_string=1)

java.lang.NullPointerException
 [1] "java.lang.NullPointerException"                                                                                     
 [2] "    water.api.DatasetServlet.doGet(DatasetServlet.java:35)"
```

I can manipulate the h2o.frame in this simple example, but it breaks with the levelone object (which I don't think I can provide easily).

```
> df <- as.data.frame(cbind(labels = letters[1:5],numbers = 1:5))
> h2o_df <- as.h2o(df)
  |========================================================================================| 100%
> print(h2o_df)
  labels numbers
1      a       1
2      b       2
3      c       3
4      d       4
5      e       5

[5 rows x 2 columns] 
> new_df <- as.data.frame(h2o_df, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> print(new_df) #converts to factors, but it's okay
  labels numbers
1      a       1
2      b       2
3      c       3
4      d       4
5      e       5
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try something and tell me if you still have an error?  Install data.table (if you don't have it already), put this at the top of your script: `options("h2o.use.data.table"=TRUE)` and then run it again.  I'm wondering if this is related to a `as.data.frame()` bug that I saw this week.

Comment: Thanks Erin, but that didn't work. A little more context, if helpful: this is on an AWS instance and I'm retrieving a saved ensemble. I'm using h2o 3.10.0.8  h2oEnsemble 0.1.8.9001 (perhaps dated, but they seem compatible).

Comment: @ErinLeDell I was able to resolve this by converting the levelone to a dataframe just after re-fitting the ensemble (instead of trying to retrieve it from a stored object).

Comment: Do you also have this error when running H2O locally?

Comment: I have not tried. I need AWS multiple cores/memory to run the models right now. I'll let you know if I do. I am thinking about shifting to h2o.stack as well.

Comment: I've made a ticket for this bug here: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-4225